# Codeigniter Date picker is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I need to add date to the form input field, but in codeigniter it is not working,here is my code in view, I don't know why it is not working, I have link web links also. it is only not working in codeigniter.**this page is loaded using ajax**.I think it would be the reason for the problem,how can I fix it????

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>


<div id="content">

 <h2>Payment Details.</h2>
<?php
          $this->load->helper('form');
          $attributes = array('method'=>'post','name'=>'payments','id'=>'payments');
          echo form_open_multipart('',$attributes);?>
    <?php //echo form_open_multipart('payments/insert_payment');?>
    <label>Payee Name: </label> <?php echo form_input('payee_name');?><br/><br/>

    <label>Address: </label> <?php echo form_input('address');?><br/><br/>

    <label>Account No: </label> <?php echo form_input('account_no');?><br/><br/>

    <label>Bank Name: </label> <?php echo form_input('bank_name');?><br/><br/>

    <label>Branch: </label> <?php echo form_input('branch');?><br/><br/>

    <label>Amount: </label> <?php echo form_input('amount');?><br/><br/>
    <label>Pick a Check Date: </label> <?php
                    $data = array(
                      'name'=> 'check_date',
                      'id' => 'datepicker',
                      'placeholder' => 'date',
                    );
echo form_input($data);?><br/><br/>

    <label>Check Number: </label> <?php echo form_input('check_number');?><br/><br/>        

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Next"/>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Comment: check console for any error

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to add two jquery files with different versions

thats why the datepicker is confused which jquery version can be used

please add `jQuery.noConflict()` before the document.ready function

Hope this helps :)

```
<script>
jQuery.noConflict();
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Datepicker is not working because `#datepicker` didn't exist yet. You could make this work by moving `('#datepicker').datepicker()` to after the point in the code where it(`#datepicker`) is created.

Comment: see my form,I have included id in date field

Comment: On rendering of page your initial request loads the page, layout, CSS, JavaScript and content.$('#datepicker').datepicker() will check for the html tag with id="datepicker". So try to include the code $('#datepicker').datepicker()  after your tag has been added.

Answer (score 1):

**Debug as following**

1> Check console.

2> Use inspect element for actual Id ( lots of frameworks changed it internally).

3> Try to put 
`$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();` at end of file

Answer (score 0):

You are adding date picker to the id

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
```

But where is this Id. You should add datepiker to the view where the id is available and add the respective javascript file also

Answer (score 0):

View:

```
$this->load->helper(array('form'));
```

Controller:

```
function datepicker(){
    $this->load->view('datepicker');
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
```

Comment: where should I put this

Comment: controller. or you can update your code changing this $this->load->helper('form'); to $this->load->helper(array('form'));

Comment: have you check your base url? is your css associated to datapicker? I can't find your #datepicker,

Comment: this is how I include CSS, JS, JQuery on view "<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">" I use base url to run those links and scripts

Comment: I need to use web links

Answer (score 0):

I saw alot of problems

1. save the style sheet inside css folder(optional) your css should inside your ci folder
2. your href in css is not the right code, if your linking css do the code below

   ```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>css/style.css" />`
   ```

make sure your `base_url` is correct. To see if this correct try to `echo base_url();`

hope this help you

Comment: using link to call script.